# App won't start on Android < 5.0 OS after updating Android SDK

Tags: android, class, classnotfoundexception, android-multidex

After I updated to the latest version of Android Studio and the Android SDK. I can't make it to run on devices below OS 5.
I have multidex, the app being big. is that the issue?
I added this to the code to my application class:

```
 @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    Log.i("","multidex installed BEFORE");
    MultiDex.install(this);
    Log.i("","multidex installed DONE");
}
```

And sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.
I get this a lot of times, as an error:

```
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134): Process: nl.hgrams.passenger, PID: 13134
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.hgrams.passenger.PSLocationCenter
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4703)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.hgrams.passenger.PSLocationCenter
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:218)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:230)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:201)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:997)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    ... 11 more
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.hgrams.passenger.PSLocationCenter
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:206)
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    ... 16 more
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: nl/hgrams/passenger/PSLocationCenter
01-13 13:13:22.296: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    ... 20 more
```

Sometimes It does manage to load the application class but then I get errors that it doesn't recognize googlemaps or Fabric or others, example:

```
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218): Process: nl.hgrams.passenger, PID: 18218
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at nl.hgrams.passenger.PSLocationCenter.onCreate(PSLocationCenter.java:167)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.onCreate(BootstrapApplication.java:263)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4730)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:175)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
 01-13 13:25:04.086: E/AndroidRuntime(18218):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm guessing it gets to the code before MultiDex.install is finished, and that's why it crashes? Am I right? And if yes, how can this be fixed?

PS: BUILD FILE: http://pastebin.com/Y2F4zYnu
Application Class: http://pastebin.com/QuuxxxbW

Comment: What `Android Studio` version, what do you mean with `5.0 OS` (API 20 -Lollipop..?), to which `SDK` did you update..? Your App was working without `MultiDex`? `MultiDex` is implementented correctly?

Comment: Untill then MultiDex was working great. It still works great on device with OS over 5.0 (API lvl 21).
Updated to Android Studio 2.0 Previews 4
Build #AI-143.2489090 build on 15 December.
SDK Tools 24.4.1 / SDK Platform Tools 23.1.0

Comment: @Amy My app was not working without multiDex. And as far as I know it is implemented correctly. I mean, this was working until 1-2 weeks when I updated Android Studio. And I was using multidex for more than 6-7 months